# Rounding up starting 6

Tags: sql-server

MSSQL rounds up at 5, can I configure it so that it round up at 6?

example:

```
select round(9.84, 1) --results in 9.8
select round(9.85, 1) --results in 9.9
select round(9.86, 1) --results in 9.9
```

I would want the result to be 9.8 when rounding of 9.85 at decimal of 1
and (9.86) results in 9.9

Comment: Just subtracting 0.01 from the value before rounding?

Comment: The OP is using SQL Server, @EladL., not MySQL

Comment: you can create a function to do that : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 4):

If you want to "round" 9.76-9.85 to to 9.8 and 9.86-9.95 to 9.9, then you need to subtract 0.01 from the value:

```
SELECT ROUND(9.85, 1); --9.90
SELECT ROUND(9.86, 1); --9.90

SELECT ROUND(9.85 - 0.01, 1); --9.80
SELECT ROUND(9.86 - 0.01, 1); --9.90
```